# 'table' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to form a relationship parent-child between two datagridviews, but I'm getting this error:

> 'table' argument cannot be null.Parameter name: table", to this line:

```
tblDataSet.Tables.Add(Table_c);
```

Does anyone know how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
private DataTable Table_c; // Table_c is imported from a local database
private DataTable Table_a; // Table_a is imported from a local database
private DataSet tblDataSet;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.table_aTableAdapter1.Fill(this.DBDataSet1.Table_a);

    this.table_cTableAdapter.Fill(this.DBDataSet1.Table_c);

    tblDataSet = new DataSet();
    tblDataSet.Tables.Add(Table_c);
    tblDataSet.Tables.Add(Table_a);


    tblDataSet.Relations.Add("Relation1",
        Table_c.Columns["Number"], Table_a.Columns["Number"]);

    BindingSource bsC = new BindingSource();
    bsC.DataSource = tblDataSet;
    bsC.DataMember = "Table_c";

    BindingSource bsA = new BindingSource();
    bsA.DataSource = bsC;
    bsA.DataMember = "Relation1";

    table_cDataGridView.DataSource = bsC;
    table_aDataGridView.DataSource = bsA; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what else to say, except Table_c is null because it hasn't been initialised. Are you trying to add this.DBDataSet1.Table_c instead?

Comment: Daren Young, yes, I did it. tblDataSet = new DataSet();

Comment: codersl, I've tried, but if I do this, I get this error: DataTable already belongs to another DataSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private DataTable Table_c;
private DataTable Table_a;
private DataSet tblDataSet;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table_a = this.table_aTableAdapter1.GetData();
    Table_c = this.table_cTableAdapter.GetData();

    tblDataSet = new DataSet();
    tblDataSet.Tables.Add(Table_a);
    tblDataSet.Tables.Add(Table_c);    
    tblDataSet.Relations.Add("Relation1", Table_c.Columns["Number"], Table_a.Columns["Number"]);

    BindingSource bsC = new BindingSource();
    bsC.DataSource = tblDataSet;
    bsC.DataMember = "Table_c";

    BindingSource bsA = new BindingSource();
    bsA.DataSource = bsC;
    bsA.DataMember = "Relation1";

    table_cDataGridView.DataSource = bsC;
    table_aDataGridView.DataSource = bsA; 
}
```

Comment: Now, I get this error:  `'column' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: column`, to  this line `tblDataSet.Relations.Add("Relation1", Table_c.Columns["Number"], Table_a.Columns["Number"]);`

Comment: hmmm... i assume that your table has a Number column. What does your TableAdapters do?

Comment: I think I should make a connection between the table and its columns from Server Explorer, but I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: the table adapter wizard should generate all the necessary code for you... you'll need to follow an online tutorial as this is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much...now it works. I will follow more tutorials to improve my knowledges.